# strange behaviour Xcode

Tags: xcode4.3

In my view controller I have a method `-(void) showDescription: (id) description` witch does **two things**:

1. displays the description in the label
2. and runs a method in the view that gives a setNeedsDisplay to the
   view.

**Now here is the strange thing:**

if i call showDescription from another method in my code, it goes to showdescription (i have an NSLog), reads the description OK ( another NSLog) but doesn't change the label or run the view method with `setNeedsDisplay` (no NSLog).

But... if i call the same method from a button it works just fine: puts up label.text and redraws my view.

I realised the same behaviour when I put two breakpoints one in `showDescription` and one in the view method. In the first case it doesn't go to the view method, in the second (UIAction) it does.

How strange is that? Does anybody have a clue why? because i'm lost....

Thanks a lot

Clemcore

classes:

- GraphViewController: UIViewController
- graphView: UIView

***GraphViewController.m****************

```
    -(void) showDescription: (id) description
    {    
      NSString* text= [(NSString*) description copy];
      self.lableDescription.text=text; //display description in label
     [self.graphView redrawView];  
    }


    -(void)displayGraph
    {
        NSLog(@"GraphViewController.displayGraph");
        NSLog(@"self.programData %@",self.programData); //these work fine
        NSLog(@"description lable %@",self.programDescriptionData);


      [self showDescription:self.programDescriptionData];
        [self.graphView redrawView];

    }

    - (IBAction)redraw {
  NSLog(@"IBAction redraw");
  NSLog(@"myData %@",self.graphView.myData);
  [self showDescription:@"CCCC"];
  [self.graphView redrawView];

}
```

*graphView.m**********

```
-(void)redrawView //public method
{
    NSLog(@"redrawView");
     [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

I am using Xcode 4.3.3 on Lion 10.7.4

Here is what happens:

If i call displayGraph, the programData and programDescriptionData is fine.(NSLog displays it correctly) but… it doesn't change the label and it doesn't go to redrawView (no NSLog redrawView).

```
Here is the log:
2012-07-08 12:29:19.193 CalculatorGraph[2641:f803] GraphViewController.displayGraph
2012-07-08 12:29:19.194 CalculatorGraph[2641:f803] self.programData (
    22
)
2012-07-08 12:29:19.194 CalculatorGraph[2641:f803] description lable 22
2012-07-08 12:29:19.195 CalculatorGraph[2641:f803] text is 22
```

Now, if i push the button it all seems to work: updates the label and redraws the view and the drawRect in the view. See my problem?

```
   2012-07-08 14:16:54.358 CalculatorGraph[2743:f803] IBAction redraw
2012-07-08 14:16:54.358 CalculatorGraph[2743:f803] myData <GraphViewController: 0x6d3f1f0>
2012-07-08 14:16:54.359 CalculatorGraph[2743:f803] text is CCCC
2012-07-08 14:16:54.359 CalculatorGraph[2743:f803] redrawView
2012-07-08 14:16:54.360 CalculatorGraph[2743:f803] redrawView
2012-07-08 14:16:54.362 CalculatorGraph[2743:f803] graphView.drawRect
2012-07-08 14:16:54.363 CalculatorGraph[2743:f803] data in graphView DrawRect is: <GraphViewController: 0x6d3f1f0>
```

Screenshot of my storyboard: please see link lower in my comments...

Thank you

Comment: if the problem is not clear or need to see some code let me know, i'll gladly oblige.

Comment: Please tag the question better; i.e. the platform, the language and the classes you are using.

Comment: Are you sure that when you call it from within your code you're actually calling the method on the right object (ie. the visible viewcontroller with IBOutlet connections to the label, etc)?  99.99999% it's coding that causes the problem, not the IDE or compiler.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the storyBoard and the IBOutlets: 


(http://a2.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/486208_10150927993067647_1533729342_n.jpg)

Comment: Sorry i'm new to this and takes me some time to decently edit my answers. How do you layout the comments?

Comment: Plus this is NOT an Xcode problem… it's an iOS, Cocoa, UIView, UIViewController issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your IBOutlet is lableDescription? Might it be labelDescription?
Plus: you should probably never "[self.graphView redrawView];"; you should be "[self.graphView setNeedsDisplay:YES]" instead. Is "showDescription" the appropriate method name? (Do you have a "hideDescription" method?).